# parse mime.types for extensions using a hash

Tags: ruby, hash

Hey guys I feel like I'm close on this, but as usual with me, I think I'm slighly messing up syntax.  The goal is to parse the mime.type file to see if the MIME type has extensions.  I have to do it in a hash.  The output should read something like, "foo/bar has extension spam,eggs, OR should read "foo/bar has no extionsions" IF the extension has no vlaue.  Here is my progress thus far:

```
#!/user/bin/ruby
#comment line
lineHash = Hash.new
File.open("/etc/mime.types", "r") do |file|
    file.each_line do |line|
            next if line[0] == ?#
            next if line == "\n"
            line = line.chomp.split
            lineHash[line[0]] = line[1..-1]
    end
end
lineHash.each do |key, value|
    if value.length == 0
            puts key + ' has no extensions.'
    else
            puts key + ' has extensions ' + value.join(',')
    end
end
```

The error I'm receiving when I run the script is:

```
parsemime.rb:13:in block in <main>': undefined method 'length' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
from parsemime.rb:12:in 'each'
from parsemime.rb:12:in '<main>'
```

Seems to be failing on the lineHash.each do |key, value| since that's line 12
line 13 (the next line) is reading an undefined method of length.

I emailed my professor for guidance and was told: "The error that I am receiving indicates that the interpreter line is incorrect. The correct path can be determined by issuing the which ruby command."

I'm not sure what that means to be honest.  I attempted to put a while before the lineHash.each do |key, value| and received a syntax error where is said unexpected "|", expecting "="

Comment: Would help if you printed out the lines as you processed them so you could see which line it is failing on.

Comment: Added my comment lines and gave a better description of where the error is occuring

Comment: Sorry, I meant which line of `/etc/mime.types` is it failing on?

Answer (score 0):

seems like you need to check that the value is not nil before trying to get its length

```
lineHash.each do |key, value|
    if !value.is_a?(Array) || value.empty?
            puts key + ' has no extensions.'
    # ...
```

Comment: Tried this method and received the same result.  The "if value.length == 0 should be pretty much the same thing as this

Comment: the difference is that you're ensuring `value` is an array before calling `length`